# Is there a way to send an object over a GET request?

Tags: node.js, http, express, post, get

I wanna make a server-side database query based on the following data from the client:

```
const passengers = {
  adults: 5,
  teens: 1,
  kids: 2,
  babies: 3,
  pets: 0
};
```

---

### What I know

I'm aware that I can send all the properties as individual query parameters, but I'm going to be sending some other ones and I'm interested in:

- Grouping some of the data I send.
- The capability of sending more complex objects with nested properties.

I'm also aware that I can switch to a POST request that accepts a JSON body, but I was willing to stick with **GET** since the **response is a list of the queried entity** and I think that GET suits better that concept as POST is rather meant for creating elements.

Is using POST the only option or can I solve this with a GET request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from putting a json string in the qurey parameters, not ideal but I think it will be more reliable than adding a body to a get request

Comment: @IvanVasiljevic Thank you for pointing out that question, I can see why you mention it. However, I'm aware that sending a body over a GET request is out of the HTTP standard. I'm asking for an alternative to it.

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa Hmm that seems the way to go, if no better one shows up that could be the right answer for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from putting a json string in the query parameters, not ideal but I think it will be more reliable than adding a body to a get request